# Java write byte[] to file - empty file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

```
// Open bin file for writing:
String s = "Hello";
FileOutputStream binOutput = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
byte[] b;
b = s.getBytes();
binOutput.write(b);
binOutput.close();
```

The above code was run from a java servlet page
After this, I checked "out.txt" but it remained empty.
It seems like a trivial task. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right file?

Comment: Are you sure the code you have here actually ran?  You don't log it in any way;  Either "out.txt" is not where you think it is, or this code didn't run.  There is nothing wrong with the sample you've posted

Comment: This code seems perfectly correct, it should copy the text.

Comment: You guys were right. I had created "out.txt" in my Java project Web Pages directory, but the java servlet has a different working directory (given by: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` ).
So the file was created in a different location.

Answer (score -1):

Flush it:

```
binOutput.write(b);
binOutput.flush();
binOutput.close();
```

Comment: No. `FileOutputStream` inherits `flush()` from `OuputStream,` where it is specified to do nothing.